# Returning from function and then coming back to same place (Python)

Tags: python

I want to return variable from function using return and after that call same function, but resume from return. It this possible? Example:

```
def abc():
    return 5
    return 6
var = abc() # var = 5
###
var = abc() # var = 6
```

Comment: have you heard about generators?

Comment: something about yield? I've heard

Comment: posted an example

Comment: You cannot do this with `return` however, if you use `yield` you can do something liek this with a generator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generator example:

```
def abc():
    yield 5
    yield 6
gen = abc()
var = next(gen) # var = 5
###
var = next(gen) # var = 6
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for a generator:

```
def abc():
    yield 5
    yield 6

gen = abc()
var = next(gen)
print(var)
var = next(gen)
print(var)
```

Answer (score 0):

returning a value in python terminates the function's process. the whole point is that it is returning exactly one  value, once being done.
maybe try to solve your problem by returning a stack- with as many values as you need,

```
def abc():
    a = []
    a.append(6)
    a.append(5)
    return a
var = abc().pop # var = 5
###
var = abc().pop # var = 6
```